# Modifying a loop based on condition checks

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

During program startup, a config value that modifies a loop's iteration speed is loaded.

For example:

```py
delay = config["delay"]

while True:
    if delay != 0:
        time.sleep(delay)
```

How could I check if a value exists only once outside of the loop? I want to avoid unnecessary condition checks during each iteration.

Comment: you could simply remove the condition, `time.sleep(0)` should not take too much time ;)

Comment: what is the problem with `while True:..time.sleep(delay)`. Why are you checking the value of `delay` ? Don't, you are checking for `sanity` of the value

Comment: It was an example condition. There could be other conditions.

Comment: The more input you give, the better answers you will get :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the check outside the loop:

```
delay = config["delay"]

if delay != 0: 
    while True:
        time.sleep(delay)
```

Or in a more concise way:

```
while delay != 0:
    time.sleep(delay)
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to believe "while true" checks something different (which you didn't state above) from what the "if" statement checks. If that's the cast, you could start with the if statement before the while loop.
I believe if they both check the same condition, while true already means delay is not equal to zero (delay != 0).
Hope I didn't misunderstand your question?